# Lithium ion batteries

Tags: lithium-ion

If mobile chargers give output of 5V DC supply to phone Li-ion battery which has maximum charge voltage of 4.2V at full charge and phone has internal circuitry to protect the battery from overcharge , if this protection circuit fails, battery gets overcharge(due to 5V supply) and possible to explode. How will this be taken care of by manufacturers ?

Comment: Charging circuitry inside the phone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to electronic design.

Answer (score 2):

Most countries/groups of countries have some markings require various safety features to allow sale of products.

IIRC the safety requirements required for UL with Li-Ion batteries state that if the charge controller of the battery fails as a short, the battery still must not be exposed to more than a 10% over voltage. There are two ways round this: have a second battery protection method or rely on some volt drop inherent in all electronics.

For second battery protection, this isn't that much of a challenge, as many devices have high side switching for some control, and low side switching for other control (personally I've designed something which had a BMIC controlling the low side, and a processor controlling high side). Or it could be a more passive method, such as a thermal fuse. These are used in various products so if the battery gets hot it isolates it completely.

As for inherent voltage drops, that's quite easy to put a protection diode in the charge path (which is a common requirement for other reason), this will drop the voltage by a chuck (0.5V is quite common) without any issues.

You are specifically talking about mobile phones which use USB to charge them. The phone usually has a dedicated USB control IC built in, this can isolate the USB power normally, and there is usually a dedicated charging control IC, which can also isolate the power. So, the quick answer is; they have two charge controllers. You could say "what if they both fail", usual safety rule would be if one is detected to fail (current still flowing when it's off) then the unit can go into a "non-operable mode", and so the user returns/throws it away rather than uses an unsafe product.

Answer (score 0):

> If mobile chargers give output of 5V DC supply to phone Li-ion battery which has maximum charge voltage of 4.2V at full charge and phone has internal circuitry to protect the battery from overcharge , if this protection circuit fails, battery gets overcharge(due to 5V supply) and possible to explode. How will this be taken care of by manufacturers ?

The key issue here is that everything may be damaged if something goes wrong in its environment.

- Houses catch fire,
- Cars crash,
- Food 'goes off',
- ... .

In the case of LiIon batteries

- The 5V input charging circuit may fail, or
- The 230 or 110 VAC circuit may fail and deliver mains voltage, or
- Lightning may strike, or
- The temperature may rise too high and damage the battery.

SO - the answer to the question is
"By appropriate electronic and mechanical design procedures aimed at taking account of the degree of damage likely from failure and the probability of it happening."
That's not a "smart alec" answer - it's what happens.
Or should be.
Sometimes they get it wrong.

In the case of LiIon chargers the consequences of failure are not trivial (fire and possible property damage and/or injury or death). So standard charging ICs are made that have a low probability of failure in a normal range of applications. Account is taken of likely mains input variations, temperatures, vibration and shock, chemical variations, quality control, ... .

And LiIon batteries are designed to "not just fail for no reason" and also to survive abuse and misuse within a normal range. Occasionally manufacturers get it wrong.
The widely publicised cellphone battery failure of recent years cost them many many millions of dollars. In that case the probability of incident  x consequence assessment was in error. So, an additional answer is "Occasionally imperfectly" :-)